# Weird align problem

Tags: html, css, css-float

If you have a look here is the code below for future references.

```
<h1>Accreditations</h1>
<p>
<strong>
  <a href="BRCCertificateE.PDF">
  <img src="images/brc.png" width="150" height="60"
  border="0" />BRC Standard</a>
</strong>
<br />The British Retail Consortium (BRC) Global Standard for
Packaging has been developed to set out hygiene and quality
requirements for packaging manufacturers</p>
<div>
  <strong>
    <a href="9001certificate.pdf">
    <img src="images/iso.png" alt="" width="150" height="60"
    border="0" />ISO900</a>
  </strong>
  <a href="#">
    <strong>1</strong>
  </a>
  <strong>:2008</strong>
  <br />
  <p>is a recognised quality management standard that we use to
  ensure we manufacture all of our products to the highest
  standards.</p>
  <p>
  <strong>
  <a href="FSC Certificate.pdf">
    <img src="images/fsc.png" width="150" height="60" border="0" />
  </a>FSC</strong>
  <strong>Chain of Custody</strong>
  <br />The Forestry Stewardship Council (FSC) monitors the use of
  timber in paper and board based products, ensuring that material
  used is coming from areas of forest that are managed responsibly.
  The FSC Chain of Custody certification tracks the FSC certified
  material through the production processes all the way to the
  store.</p>
  <p>
  <strong>Environmental issues</strong>
  <br />These have to be at the top of the agenda for the customer
  and for the packaging producer. We believe that cartonboard
  represents the most environmentally friendly form of packaging
  available due to the consumer being able to recycle 100% of the
  product.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help you geniuses think of

Comment: Your `<html>` markup was invalid.  I corrected it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the images in the second link are `float: left`, influencing the document flow underneath.

The cleanest way to fix it is to add

```
clear: both
```

to the `<p>` element that encloses the third item.

Answer (score 0):

add this as attribute to your fsc link

```
style="display: block; width: 60px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding on the `<p>` above it is not large enough to break below the images. So the affected `<p>` is actually still next to the images from the `<p>` above it.